# в AsyncTask не меняется значение переменной

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Написал код с использованием AsyncTask, который по окончанию в onPostExecute должен менять статичную переменную главного класса.
AsyncTask запускается по нажатию кнопки, и меняет переменную только после полной отработки, а не во время. В результате для изменения значения переменной на кнопку приходится нажимать дважды.
Как это можно исправить?

---

Метод, в котором должна меняться переменная (находится в другом классе):

```
@Override //
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    String resultPOST = "Сервер ничего не выдал";
    resultPOST = s;
    MainActivity.serverAnswer+=resultPOST;
}
```

---

Главный класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static Button logInButton;

static String serverAnswer = "Ответ от сервера:\n";
String pass,login;
public static TextView serverAnswerTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    logInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    serverAnswerTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void onClickLogIn(View v){
    TextView mLogIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    login = mLogIn.getText().toString();
    TextView mPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    pass = mPass.getText().toString();
    new LocationSender().execute(login);
    serverAnswerTextView.setText(serverAnswer);
}
```

---

Забыл добавить. Если в onPostExecute я меняю значение TextView напрямую (не через переменную) она меняется сразу, без повторного нажатия.

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String resultPOST = "Сервер ничего не выдал";
    resultPOST = s;
    MainActivity.serverAnswer+=resultPOST;
    //текст метки меняется сразу же
    MainActivity.serverAnswerTextView.setText (MainActivity.serverAnswerTextView.getText()+resultPOST);
}
```

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как работает `AsyncTask`. Рекомендую посмотреть видеоуроки по асинктаскам прежде, чем пытаться их использовать

Comment: я действительно работаю с ним впервые. Есть ли что-то у Вас на примете что могло бы мне помочь в этом?

Comment: Гугл может помочь https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20asynctask%20lesson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Завершение метода `AsyncTask.execute(login)` не означает что к этому моменту поток завершил работу. Данный метод только запускает поток, он не ждет его завершения, следовательно на момент вызова метода `serverAnswerTextView.setText(serverAnswer);` после запуска `AsyncTask'a` в переменной `serverAnswer` еще ничего нет.

Правильным решением будет убрать установку текста после запуска асинк такса, и оставить в методе `onPostExecute`. Он для того и создан, чтобы обработать результат работы задачи.

Более подробней про `AsyncTask` читайте в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: @Jorik что-то я не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Решение здесь одно - менять в ```onPostExecute```

Comment: Прошу прощение, я не сразу понял Ваш ответ.